# Odata: External Object Create new data in external data source error

Tags: odata

I'm trying to create new data in the external data source. 
create new data through any client tool works correctly but when i try to do the same clicking on new button on SFDC i got this message :

Error: Invalid Data. 
Review all error messages below to correct your data.
. Error received: 403: CSRF token validation failed

Any advice ?

Thank you

Comment: Did you find the answer to your question? Did you contact Salesforce support? Did you resolve your issue?

Comment: I guess CSRF is security setting, so your data do not have correct token to prevent Cross-Site Request Forgery (CSRF) attack .